# InetAddress.getLocalHost() gives different address

Tags: java, localhost, ip-address, inet

InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() gives different address on 2 git branches on my machine.
one branch gives me 127.0.0.1, other gives me my machines private address 10.x.x.x.

Not sure what is the reason?

```
/etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
f***::1%lo0 localhost
127.0.0.1   administrators-MacBook-Pro-3.local
127.0.0.1   LX-X-XXXXX
```

Comment: What's the difference between the branches?

Comment: upload a patch with the difference between the branches..

Comment: is 10.x.x.x machine is VM or connected to some network ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: There is no difference in the call and this particular class.

Comment: @Naruto, yeah it is a business network.